# What do I do with a pointer to a pointer to an interface in C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I'm calling a windows function that has the following definition:

```
HRESULT getElementById(BSTR v, IHTMLElement **pel)
```

So I have the following usage:

```
CComBSTR v = "myid";
IHTMLElement** element;
HRESULT hr = pDocument->getElementById(v, element);
```

Now what do I do with element to make is useful to me?

I want to get to the properties and methods of element, but I don't know how to go about it.

Can somebody help please.

Comment: `(**element).property`? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Excellent - thank you

Comment: You're passing by value an unintialized `IHTMLElement**` to a function that takes `IHTMLElement**`. Something's not right here...

Comment: I'm assuming that the method fills it in for me.  Would that be a wrong assumption?

Comment: Well, you need to pass the address of a `IHTMLElement*`, not the value of a `IHTMLElement**`.

Comment: ok - what is the syntax for that

Comment: Declare `IHTMLElement* element` and pass `&element`. And of course, make sure that `hr` is good before attempting to use `element` (which could be left uninitialized if the function has failed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is most likely the wrong way to call the function. The `getElementById` function takes a pointer to a pointer because it emulates *pass by reference*, and will write to the dereferenced pointer inside the function. Since you pass an uninitialized pointer you will get *undefined behavior* and probably a crash.

What you should do instead is to declare a single pointer variable, and pass a pointer to that variable. Like

```
CComBSTR v = "myid";
IHTMLElement* element;
HRESULT hr = pDocument->getElementById(v, &element);
```

As for how to get attributes etc., I recommend that you [read a reference for `IHTMLElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752279(v=vs.85).aspx). Perhaps search for tutorials or examples as well?